# In a Haskell script, how does one programatically obtain the type signature of a function?

Tags: function, haskell, types, signature

In Haskell (GHC), how can one obtain the type signature of the list of functions shown below?

```
[tail,init,reverse]
```

I unsuccessfully tried using the `typeOf` function of the `Data.Typeable` module. Specifically, I try to run the following Haskell script:

```
import Data.Typeable
import Test.HUnit
myTest = TestCase
          ( assertEqual "\n\nShould have been \"[[a] -> [a]]\""
            "[[a] -> [a]]"
            (show ( typeOf [tail,init,reverse] )) )
tests = TestList [ (TestLabel "myTest" myTest) ]
```

However, GHC responds with the following error:

```
C:\>ghci my_script.hs
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( my_script.hs, interpreted )
my_script.hs:7:21: error:
    * No instance for (Typeable a0) arising from a use of `typeOf'
    * In the first argument of `show', namely
        `(typeOf [tail, init, reverse])'
      In the third argument of `assertEqual', namely
        `(show (typeOf [tail, init, reverse]))'
      In the first argument of `TestCase', namely
        `(assertEqual
            "\n\
            \\n\
            \Should have been \"[[a] -> [a]]\""
            "[[a] -> [a]]"
            (show (typeOf [tail, init, reverse])))'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Prelude>
```

---

**Update:** The following HUnit test case isn't quite what I wanted, but I did get it to pass (based on David Young's suggestion).  This test case at least forces the compiler to confirm that `[tail,init,reverse]` is of type `[ [a] -> [a] ]`.

```
import Data.Typeable
import Test.HUnit
myTest = TestCase
          ( assertEqual "\n\nShould have been 3"
            3
            ( length ( [tail,init,reverse] :: [[a]->[a]] ) ) )
tests = TestList [ (TestLabel "myTest" myTest) ]
```

```
C:\>my_script.hs
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( my_script.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> runTestTT tests
Cases: 1  Tried: 1  Errors: 0  Failures: 0
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as stated, but: What are you trying to do? The compiler will already automatically check to see if a type signature fits.

Comment: Essentially, I am trying to get the HUnit test case to pass.

Comment: But what I'm saying is, that is unnecessary. You can just have something like `main = return () where _ = [tail, init, reverse] :: [[a] -> [a]]` and the compiler will automatically tell you whether the type signature is valid as part of its type checking process (at compile time).

Comment: Let's go one layer deeper.  Why are you writing unit tests for types?  Some people would consider that unnecessary since programs are type checked at compile time.  What do you gain by ensuring the type matches what you expected at some prior date?  Are you trying to make your unit tests ensure the API hasn't changed?

Comment: In response to the edit: You really don't need a unit test at all. If that signature in the code failed to type check, the code won't even run at all. The compiler would reject the program during compilation and provide an appropriate error message. This is a big reason for having a static type system in the first place, actually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a unit test to check a function's type. A unit tests runs after the code has been compiled, it's a dynamic test. However, type checking is a static test: all types are tested during the compilation of your program. Therefore, we can use GHC as a minimal static type checker and reduce your program to:

```
main :: IO ()
main = return ()
  where
    tailInitReverseAreListFunctions :: [[a] -> [a]]
    tailInitReverseAreListFunctions = [tail, init, reverse]
```

You don't even need that test anymore the moment you actually *test* your functions with real data, because that application will (statically) test the function's type too.

Remember, Haskell is a statically typed language. The types are checked during compilation, *before* your code is run. Any type checking unit-test is therefore more or less a code-smell, because it can only pass.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for your comments.  You make good points.